# Highly customizable PHP CMS. The Ultimate Content Management System & Framework

Tags: php, drupal, frameworks, joomla, content-management-system

I have a client who wants a paid member site. It's a big network of companies. If a company wants to become a member then they can apply online. If my client likes them after their manual inspections & field visits of said company, they can approve it for online payment and after the payment the company becomes a member or of-course they can just disapprove it.

- Every member gets one page
- Every member can edit their own information anytime and only their own information

Apart from this, the site will have a pictures module, youtube videos module and a blog module, all for the network not any members.

What I need to know is what PHP CMS technically CMF is capable of doing this. I have read that Drupal is very flexible, Joomla is less flexible but easier. I have seen extremely customized apps built on Drupal like:

- **Open Atrium**
- **Open Publish**
- **Open Public**
- **Managing News**

Drupal looks very promising.

- **Is what I need posible in Joomla or Drupal?**
- **Is there any other CMS that could do this? or do this better than Drupal or Joomla?**

This is an important decision for me as the chosen CMS would then become the main CMS my company would work on.

I am inclined towards a CMS and not a custom framework backed application as I want to settle an open source CMS for my company.

Please share if know of a CMS in which it is possible to make the features I need.

Also please share your good and bad experiences with various CMS'. All the little developer experience information would be helpful.

Let's make this the goto CMS & CMF article for anybody.

I will start: WordPress is my favorite CMS because of the small learning curve and the flexibility functions.php provides me. But I am sure it is not quite capable of providing for this project.

Thanks! I appreciate all the help.

Comment: is this not what the client is *paying* **you** for ?

Comment: No CMS would have all these features built in. Which is why I want CMS with a framework so that whatever doesn't come out of the box can be made. All I am asking here is the capabilities of different systems and frameworks. Client wants features (all of them) and that's what they're paying me for.

Comment: Aayush- Go with Drupal, it should get you there. Run away from Joomla, extending it is a nightmare my experience.

Comment: Ahh... too late my friend I'm already on the brink of finishing the site with Joomla. None the less I have realized that extending Joomla is hard. I'm gonna go with Drupal for my next site. Thanks for the reply anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My $0.02

If you are more experienced with WP, then you properly should use that instead of learning a new CMS on this quite important project (as I assume based on your description).

As for Druapl, it is quite flexible with

- template overwrite system
- custom module based on the apis

and also has lots of the features you asked built-in:

- user management
- user based Content editing
- pictures module
- youtube videos module
- blog module

If you do go for Drupal, I would recommend version 6 instead of 7 because of the larger module library and user base, hence you have better chance found modules you want already built by someone instead of start from scratch.

When you need a lot customization and performance, you should go for a framework rather than CMS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The project in itself is not that important, the decision is more important. Is Drupal's user management feature capable of doing the partial approval and disapproval until the payment is made? Rest of the features that I need are quite generic and like you said most come out of the box or as modules. I am not going to mark this solved yet. I want more people to share their opinions on different systems. I really appreciate you taking the time. Thanks!

Comment: Arrhh.. I just saw a moderator, Robert Harvey, closed this as this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. That was kind of the intent. I don't see how it is not constructive to lay down the pro's and con's of different systems. It would serve as a very helpful read for anyone looking to choose a CMS or CMF for their app.

Is there a way I can get in touch with him?

Comment: @will.c recommending that he goes with version 6 is terrible advice- version 7 has huge advantages, and why would you invest in time in developing to an older version that you will have to eventually port anyway?

Comment: @Yarin, I do agree that Druapl 7 is the way to go, however the question was more focus on finding existing modules. Hence I recommend Druapl 6 because at the time question is asked, Drupal 6 is just more established, sadly that is still the case right now given a lot of the modules for 7 are still in dev or alpha (which you may want to argue)